# form stop working after jquery div refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

The logic that I wanted to achieve is :

1. Click on #MyButton -> works,
2. makes jquery script to works with #Mydiv -> works,
3. Jquery script refresh the content of page ((rand(10,100)) is used to visualize the refresh -> works,
4. Once jquery refreshes the page, the button submit the form is not clickable anymore -> Not Working after one div refresh.

The idea is to reload a dynamic php/mysql using order by rand() page that contains data and a submit form button -> this works but all the buttons submit  link to forms are not working anymore after jquery reload. Jquery is still working all the time after div reload.

This example works well and refreshes the content inside of #Mydiv, but once the jquery refresh is done with (id="MyButton") impossible to click on the button(id="TEST_ID" type="submit") located inside of #Mydiv to reload the form (button d="TEST_ID" type="submit" is unclickable). To be able to click on the form button again (submit), I need to reload the page entirely and manually. It works as long as I don't use jquery div reload. Once I reload the div, the button to make the HTML form becomes unclickable gain until I reload the page manually

```
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js"></script>
<script>

    $(window).on('load', function(e) {

        $('#MyButton').on('click', function(e) {

            //alert('Submitting')

             e.preventDefault();

            $("#Mydiv").load(" #Mydiv > *");

        });

    });

</script>
</head>
<!--will Refresh this section -->

<div id="Mydiv">
    <div class="container text-center">
        
            <form name="test_reload" id="TEST_ID" method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?> ">

                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" value="TEST_ID" name='TEST_ID' id="TEST_ID" type="submit">

                    TEST FOR FORM SUBMIT
                </button>
            </form>
     
        <hr />

        <h1><?php // FOR TEST PUPORSE TO VISUALIZE THE REFRESH  
                    echo "TEST-RELOAD" . (rand(10, 100));
            ?>
        </h1>

    </div>

</div>

<!--will Refresh this section -->

<button id="MyButton" class="btn btn-warning">Refresh</button>

</body>
```

Comment: What "stops working" about the form?  This appears to be a plain HTML form with no JavaScript event handler attached to it, so it's not clear how or why `preventDefault` is involved.  Can you clarify what specific problem you are experiencing?

Comment: @DarkBee: Is that the case here, though?  The only event handler shown is on `#MyButton`, which is outside the `<div>` being "refreshed".

Comment: Though looking at the HTML... There's a `<button>` inside a `<form>` **inside a `<button>`**?  That makes very little sense.

Comment: Your `load` function doesn't know where to get the data from, because you didn't provide the URL of the page. Though, there might be a better solution. What do you actually want to accomplish by "refreshing" the form?

Comment: Its a sample to achieve a jquery refresh of a page containing a form. The jquery refresh works very well. But once I refresh the page once, the "button submit" for form stops accepting clicks ( Not working). I want to reload a page with jquery; this page contains MySQL/data and some buttons to submit a form. I used PHP (rand(10,100)) to visualize the refresh of the page. The logic is -> refresh page with Jquery, -> this also refreshes the dynamic content PHP/MySQL of the page--> that content a submit button--> that fire a form( in this test, the form is empty and reload the page)

Comment: Please provide enough, *correct* code.  Your code states "Refresh this section" but that section would not be refreshed *given the code provided*.  It's likely (given the comment) that "MyButton" *is* recreated.  To test/confirm/fix, change `$('#MyButton').on('click', function (e) {` to `$(document).on("click", '#MyButton', function (e) {`

Comment: @Sam: So, to clarify for the community here... `#MyButton` *does* continue to work after "refreshing the div", it's *only* the `<button>` *in the form* which "does not work"?  For one thing, which `<button>` are you referring to?  Again, *the form itself* is inside of a `<button>`, which makes no sense and is likely very invalid.  Start with sensible, valid markup.  Remove that "outer" `<button>` around the `<form>` element entirely.  Does that correct the problem?  If not, in what way does the form's button "not accept clicks"?  How specifically are you observing this?

Comment: @David In my example, there are two buttons; one to refresh a page that contains a form with a submit button. The idea is to refresh with jquery a PHP page with MySQL data. This PHP page includes a form with a submit button. The idea is to avoid a Jquery scroll Loading or a Php/MySQL.(next1)(next2) etc. I load a php page MySQL ORDER BY RAND() with limit LIMIT 0,20, and at the bottom of the page, I put a (MORE) button that calls the jquery load script to reload random data. This avoids complicated process of next / or ajax/jquery infinity scroll load. This a another approach to displaying data

Comment: that's fine, but given your code, there's no reason reloading myDiv would change anything about the form, given that the form appears to have no javascript attached to it. Reloading some random html won't affect how that html on it's own functions.

Comment: @Sam: *"In my example, there are two buttons"* - In the code shown there are three buttons.  One of which is **nested with** another.  Which is invalid and highly likely to lead to unexpected behavior.  Again, always start with valid markup.

Comment: the invalid html is certainly interesting, but unlikely to be relevant to the problem if the html "works" (whatever that means) prior to reloading it

Comment: @Kevin B@David I will make an online working example to show you the code and my problem. Thanks for your patience

Comment: @Sam online working examples don't help future users identify whether or not the question you're asking is relevant to them. Your problem needs to be entirely represented within your question here.

Comment: @KevinB clarifications: My example works well and refreshes the content inside of #Mydiv, but once the jquery refresh is done (id="MyButton") impossible to click on the button(d="TEST_ID" type="submit") located inside of #Mydiv to reload the form (button d="TEST_ID" type="submit" is unclickable). To be able to click on the form button again (submit), I need to reload the page entirely and manually. The jquery button (id="MyButton") never stops refreshing the data/page. That is why I believe it's a problem within my jquery code. My jquery level has reached its limits here.

Comment: @Sam: Aside from potential side-effects of the invalid HTML structure, there's nothing we're seeing in the code shown which would indicate why that form would "work" the first time it renders and not the next time it renders.  If you can provide an off-site example of the problem, though not ideal, that may be the only way to help you at this point.  The *best* approach would be to encapsulate that example into a [mcve] in the question above.

Comment: @Sam yes exactly , after the first refresh is pushed ( id="MyButton")  (jquery), the div continues to work well with the jquery script refreshing the div; only the second button(form) name='TEST_ID' type="submit stops until I decide to reload the page manually. After reloading, the form button works again until I push the jquery button to refresh the div (id="MyButton"); then, the form/button(name='TEST_ID' ) does not work anymore until I reload the page, and so on...

Comment: @freedomn-m Sorry, your  To test/confirm/fix, change $('#MyButton').on('click', function (e) { to $(document).on("click", '#MyButton', function (e) { is not working. Refresh div is working, but click on button (name='TEST_ID' ) to make form submit not clickable after first refresh of div. thanks for trying

Comment: @Emiel Zuurbier I dont need data or url because it's a sample TEST, I just need the button submit of the form to be able to be cilckable (means the form works)

Comment: "*impossible to click on the button(d="TEST_ID" type="submit") located inside of #Mydiv to reload the form*" - well, this is *very* different from the previous description, so no wonder event-delegation on MyButton doesn't work.  Perhaps you could update the question the *actual* issue - specifically including collating all the additional information added in the comments?

Comment: @freedomn-m  Once the jquery runs( id="MyButton")
--jquery is doing its job to refresh the div #Mydiv
--, all the page content inside the div #Mydiv
 is refreshed (including a form located inside the div #Mydiv
). Once the refresh is successfully done, the form inside of the div#Mydiv doesn't work anymore as the button submit the form(name='TEST_ID'
) is not clickable anymore unless I reload the whole page. Then the button (name='TEST_ID'
) becomes clickable again until I refresh the div.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification update.  The problem is a bit clearer.   Can you confirm it still doesn't work if you fix your HTML?  At the moment you have invalid HTML (nested `<button>`), so it's down to the browser how it renders - and it's quite likely that the jquery way of handling your invalid HTML is what is causing it to break.

Comment: @freedomn-m you where right it was an invalid HTML (nested <button>) that was creating the bug to block the form button--Thanks a lot!

Comment: @David  with user freedomn-m  you where also both right it was an invalid HTML (nested <button>) that was creating the bug to block the form button, I did no pay that much attention to your comment, because I was so sure it was a Jquery coding error --Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for providing feedback - glad you got it fixed.

Answer (score -2):

$('#submitBtn').on('click', function (e) {
        
            e.preventDefault();
             
          });

Comment: The jquery button ( id="MyButton")  and the form button (name='TEST_ID' ) are doing different job that works well separately. It's when they are on the same page that the jquery button  to refresh the div blocks the form button from working more than one time. The form button is plain HTML, with no jquery. The problem seems to come from the jquery script itself. This is maybe because the page has been sent to the browser, and I am sending a behind-the-scenes request. I have no idea how to rewrite the jquery script to make the browser to be able to "see" the HTML form after div refresh

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).